# How to animate two UIView flip in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uibutton

in my main ViewController i have 2 UIView's named as AppointmentView  and BookView and i have placed a UIButton on both UIView's on click on that i need to flip each view.

I have added below code, but the problem is when i click on UIButton its flipping and coming to same page (not to second view).

Please help me

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.bookAppointmentView cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bookAppointmentView];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Updated code

```
- (IBAction)addnewPatient:(id)sender {
    self.createNewPatientView.hidden=NO;
    self.bookAppointmentView.hidden=YES;
    self.createNewPatientView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:254.0/255.0 green:254.0/255 blue:254.0/255 alpha:1];
    self.createNewPatientView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    self.createNewPatientView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.bookAppointmentView toView:self.createNewPatientView duration:.6 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft  | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews) completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         //completion code goes here
     }];

}
- (IBAction)existingPatient:(id)sender {
    self.bookAppointmentView.hidden=NO;
    self.createNewPatientView.hidden=YES;
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.createNewPatientView toView:self.bookAppointmentView duration:.6 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft  | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews) completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         //completion code goes here
     }];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have better do this with animation blocks like:

```
[UIView transitionFromView:view1 toView:view2 duration:.3 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft  | UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews) completion:^(BOOL finished) 
    {
            //completion code goes here 
    }];
```

Cheers!

Comment: its fliping but very fast and but not coming back...when i click on button in secondview to flip its flipping and first view is not showing

Comment: yes the flipping is working  but it flipping entire viewcontroller. is there any way to flip only these 2 views?

Comment: You should replace the `view1` with your `AppointmentView` and `view2` with `BookView` and everything should work. `view1` and `view2` are the parameters passed to the animation method in my sample code. Don't pass `self.view` as a parameter to that method.

Comment: When using `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews` option of the animation, you don't have to hide the views manually. Remove `self.bookAppointmentView.hidden=NO;
    self.createNewPatientView.hidden=YES;`

Comment: but that wont solve my problem , it still flipping entire viewcontroller